# Why do we not repair the Mishna according to the emendations of the Talmud?

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna, text

Often times in analyzing a Mishna the Talmud will say that the Mishna is missing certain information and should read as follows - חסורי מחסרא והכי קתני. The Talmud will then posit the missing information which will allow the Mishna's reading to make sense.

Assuming this type of reading is meant to be taken literally, as [some authorities do](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18484/how-do-we-understand-the-idea-of-something-missing-from-the-mishnah-%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%90) (see numbers 5, 6), why was the text of the Mishna not emended to follow the reading of the Talmud?

Comment: "Assuming this type of reading is meant to be taken literally" why assume that? Maybe no one assumes that and that's why no one emmended the text

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83149/8775 for the various views on what this means. Only according to some does it mean that the text was emended.

Comment: @DoubleAA isn't that the plain meaning of the text? I would argue that the burden of proof is on any other approach

Comment: Even if it means that they changed the text, that doesn't mean that the text of the Mishna isn't useful. It is useful in learning the gemara in the first place. Furthermore, the yerushalmi doesn't engage in this method on the Mishna, so these changes aren't unanimous, so it a lot of sense to leave the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we understand the idea of something missing from the mishnah חסורי מיחסרא והכי קתני?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18484/how-do-we-understand-the-idea-of-something-missing-from-the-mishnah-%d7%97%d7%a1%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%99-%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%97%d7%a1%d7%a8%d7%90)

Comment: @mevaqesh I'm not sure I understand your points. Isn't the reason the gemarah comes on to the solution that the text is corrupted specifically because one cannot learn the Mishna in any other logical way? Regarding the Yerushalmi that is an interesting point.

Comment: Maybe given a set of assumptions (e.g. a particular halakic position) the Bavli will employ this method, but it is rarely if ever the only possibility.

Comment: @danny doesn't seem like a dupe. This asks why not edit mishnayot. That asks what a particular expression means; two different questions.

Comment: https://www.machonso.org/uploads/images/%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%A5_2.pdf אולי יעזור

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. A few ideas: (1) as you can see from the sources brought in [this thread](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18484/how-do-we-understand-the-idea-of-something-missing-from-the-mishnah-%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%90) most commentators do not take the phrase to mean literally that the girsa of the mishna needs to be corrected. (2) Even though some commentators do take it that way (e.g., Halichot Olam), we aren't going to mess with the text based on a safek, especially if it's a minority view. (3) Even if the gemara means the mishnah's text is mistaken, the correcting of the mishnah is part of the give and take of the Talmud. Including it is similar to the inclusion of rejected opinions, rejected hava aminas, misunderstood opinions, even other kinds of corrections ("if it was said, it was said like this" or "this is what I meant"). Rashi does sometimes give a heads-up on the Mishnah that the gemara is going to mess with the girsa. Though this third explanation may not explain why we don't make the corrections in printed collections of the Mishnah separate from the Talmud assuming such editions serve an independent, non-talmud-related purpose.